# Need to run Monthly Reports in Oracle via SQL Code

Tags: oracle, sqlcode

newbie here, I simply need to get an Oracle report, which I have successfully gotten to run weekly using code: CAST("AR Origination Date"."Day Cal Date" AS DATE) BETWEEN (current_date)-1 AND (current_date)-0

I for the life of me cannot, trying several sql code attempts get a monthly report run. I do not need to group, nor count. I just need this report to run monthly. Does anyone have any ideas? I've tried a few things I've found online only to get errors.

Attached is a picture of what I'm dealing with.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1RaC.png)

Sorry, deleted all tries of everything.

Comment: Which tool are you using? I'm not familiar with what screenshot shows; can't tell for the rest of community, but it would probably help if you shared that info.

Comment: `somedate >= trunc(date '2023-12-21, 'mm') and somedate < trunc(add_months(date '2023-12-21', 1), 'mm')`

Comment: Littlefoot, thanks for the suggestion. I apologize. I am using Oracle Analytics Publisher for OAS. This may be too much, but here it goes:  I click edit on my already generated report, click on Criteria to view what Oracle calls "Filters" (what you see in the picture I uploaded), I hover over the filter I want to edit, select the edit filter button, select the "Convert this Filter to SQL" button, and the "Advanced SQL Filter" pop up comes up where I paste in SQL code (which hopefully works (like the weekly code did). The code astentx provided produces an error.

Comment: Let me be a little more specific. I then set, through Oracle selected steps in Publisher, when this report runs, which will be the 1st of the month, every month. Not sure if that helps. (Time 7:32 am EST)